# Removing the Parent Tags having Child Tags with duplicate values

Tags: xslt-1.0

How to remove the Parent Tags having Child Tags with duplicate values.

I have already used code do some modifications but was unable to get all the results
This was the output I was getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">

    <Header> </Header>
      <Body>
        <MessageParts xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
          <Run xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Run">

            <RunObject class="entity">
              <A1>NA</A1>
              <A2>False</A2>
              <A3>02</A3>
              <A4>ER</A4>
            </RunObject>

            <RunObject class="entity">
              <A1>NA</A1>
              <A2>False</A2>
              <A3>03</A3>
              <A4>ER</A4>
            </RunObject>

             <RunObject class="entity">
              <A1>NA</A1>
              <A2>False</A2>
              <A3>02</A3>
              <A4>ER</A4>
            </RunObject>

             <RunObject class="entity">
              <A1>NA</A1>
              <A2>False</A2>
              <A3>02</A3>
              <A4>ER</A4>
            </RunObject>


          </Run>
        </MessageParts>
      </Body>
    </Envelope>
```

I wanted to remove the namespaces, rename the Parent tags and rearrange the child tags and remove Parent Tags having child tags with duplicate values.

So I used this code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message"
    xmlns:r="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Run"
    exclude-result-prefixes="m r">
      <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
      <xsl:key name="RunObject" match="r:RunObject[@class='entity']" use="concat(generate-id(parent::*), A1, '|', A2, '|' , A3, '|' , A4  )" />

      <!-- move all elements to no namespace -->
      <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:template>

      <!-- rename MessageParts to Document + skip the Run wrapper -->
      <xsl:template match="m:MessageParts">
        <Document>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="r:Run/*"/>
        </Document>
      </xsl:template>

     <!-- Removing duplicate parent tags -->
      <xsl:template match="r:Run">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="r:RunObject[@class='entity'][generate-id(.) = generate- 
          id(key('RunObject', concat(generate-id(parent::*), A1, '|', A2, '|' ,  
         A3, '|' , A4)) [1])]" />
       </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
      <!-- rename RunObject to Item + reorder child nodes -->
      <xsl:template match="r:RunObject[@class='entity']">
        <Item>

          <xsl:apply-templates select="r:A3" />
          <xsl:apply-templates select="r:A4" />
          <xsl:apply-templates select="r:A2" />
          <xsl:apply-templates select="r:A1" />
        </Item>
      </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I was able to remove the namespaces, rename the parent tags and was able to rearrange the child tags as well but was unable to remove the parent tags having child tags with duplicate values.
    This is the output that i got after using the above code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope>

  <Header> </Header>
  <Body>
    <Document>

      <Item>
        <A3>02</A3>
        <A4>ER</A4>
        <A2>False</A2>
        <A1>NA</A1>
      </Item>

      <Item>
        <A3>03</A3>
        <A4>ER</A4>
        <A2>False</A2>
        <A1>NA</A1>
      </Item>

      <Item>
        <A3>02</A3>
        <A4>ER</A4>
        <A2>False</A2>
        <A1>NA</A1>
      </Item>

      <Item>
        <A3>02</A3>
        <A4>ER</A4>
        <A2>False</A2>
        <A1>NA</A1>
      </Item>

    </Document>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

This is the expected output

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Envelope>

      <Header> </Header>
      <Body>
        <Document>

          <Item>
            <A3>02</A3>
            <A4>ER</A4>
            <A2>False</A2>
            <A1>NA</A1>
          </Item>

          <Item>
            <A3>03</A3>
            <A4>ER</A4>
            <A2>False</A2>
            <A1>NA</A1>
          </Item>

       </Document>
     </Body>
    </Envelope>
```

Comment: Please stop reposting the same question.

Comment: I have made the changes according to my code, still unable to get the desired result

Comment: The solution that i am expecting is that even possible?